# What is the difference between mvc2 and mvc3 template in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the difference between mvc2 and mvc3 template in visual studio? Can I use MVC2 template instead of MVC3 template? Just a beginner, so want to create some samples in MVC3 framework.

Comment: Don't use MVC2. It's older, and not nearly as cool to use.

Answer (score 0):

MVC3 has some new updated feature than MVC2

### Top Features in MVC3

- Integrated Scaffolding system extensible via NuGet
- HTML 5 enabled project templates
- Expressive Views including the new Razor View Engine
- Powerful hooks with Dependency Injection and Global Action Filters
- Rich JavaScript support with unobtrusive JavaScript, jQuery Validation, and JSON binding

Comment: Can I use mvc2 template instead of mvc3? Cause I have only mvc2 template installed.

Comment: ya, surely you can use MVC2 template

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx) article.

To name few following are list of some advantages of MVC3 over MVC2.

1. You can use the Razor View Engine, which depending on your requirements, it will make your view code nicer.
2. Partial Page output caching is a great feature for systems that share bits and pieces across different UI's.
3. Unobtrusive JavaScript and Validation is also another great new feature that will help you keep your code's maintainability among other benefits.
4. MVC3 also has some benefits from the dynamic aspects of .NET 4, and that also helps you keep your view code cleaner.
5. NuGet Package Manager
   Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points of difference among the two:

1.View Engine :View Engine is responsible for rendering of the HTML code from your views to the browser.
MVC 2 uses only Web Forms view engine (.aspx) as a default View Engine.
MVC3 uses Razor View Engine (.cshtml for c# and .vbhtml for Visual Basic) and Web Forms view engine (.aspx).

2.Syntax :
(HTML Syntax) Web Forms view engine syntax: <%=Html code %> in MVC2.
(Razor Syntax) Razor View Engine syntax: @Html code in MVC3.

3.Chart, WebGrid, Crypto,WebImage, WebMail Controls :
All these are not available in MVC2.
All these are available in MVC3 and in MVC4.

4.Objects available for sharing of data between View and Controller :
TempData, ViewData are available in MVC2.
TempData, ViewData ,ViewBag are available in MVC3.